# Flutter local notifications triggered by GPS location

Tags: flutter, notifications, localnotification

QQ:I have set up local notifications in my flutter app that are triggered at a certain time. However, now I would also like to add notification for when the device is taken 1km within a certain local.  Any help or direction would be helpful.  I have spent countless hours searching for information and guidance but have found nothing. Maybe flutter doesn’t have this capability.

Comment: You can use Android platform channel to use [Context Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/overview)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Geolocator** package: [Geolocator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator)

First save your currentLocation using `getCurrentPosition` method.

It has `getPositionStream` method which gives you new position whenever our position changes.

Whenever location change use `distanceBetween` method to find the distance between them. The method returns the distance in meteres.

Whenever distance gets more than 1000m trigger notification.

API reference for Geolocator: [Geolocator API docs](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/geolocator/latest/)